# how to implement purchase from a Zen Cart shop without creating an account?

Tags: shopping-cart, zen-cart

[This feature request is already on Zen Cart's roadmap](http://tutorials.zen-cart.com/index.php?article=16)

However, i would like to implement this on an e-commerce site that i'm building, and i can't sit around and wait for the Zen Cart team to enable it. Has anyone else attempted to do this? Een some guidelines would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an add-on for this called COWOA. It's easy to set up and it works.

http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=1655